# Microsoft Report Viewer to convert export to pdf, it cuts half the report off and puts it on a second page

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

Microsoft report Viewer to convert export to PDF, it cuts half the report off and puts it on a second page. When report is  converted to PDF form the system, the document is cut off over 2 pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the dimensions of your Page control.

Typically the PDF is going to emulate a 8.5" by 11" piece of paper - considering margins you should keep the width of your report width to less than 7.5".

If you want to support non standard sizes, take a look at [how to change paper size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155929%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

To ensure that your body doesn't overflow your report, you can check in report designer that dimensions of the body are less than dimensions of the report.